# InternalType of JSONField is shown as TextField

Tags: django, django-jsonfield

I am a beginner with DJANGO, I am working on a project where one of the models contains a JSONField. In the code at some point i need to detect and process the JSONField only and so I get the internaltype of the fields and if it turns out to be JSON field then I process it.

```
for field in obj._meta.fields:
            #find the fields with JSONField type
            if obj._meta.get_field(field.name).get_internal_type() == 'JSONField':
```

It works well on my machine, however when I upload the same code on the server, it does not execute, as, the internaltype of the JSONField is returned as a TextField and the logic fails there. What could be wrong and why is the JSONField being detected as a TextField?

The postgres version being used on the server is 9.6.1

Comment: Do you have the same version on your development machine as on production? I'm using 9.6.11 on production and couldn't reproduce your issue. I get JSONField as expected.

Comment: @dirkgroten Thanks for your efforts! On my development machine I am using postgres version 11.1. Also I am using it from within a docker container.